# If $f$ is odd and periodic then a translation of $f$ is even?

Tags: real-analysis, periodic-functions, even-and-odd-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a odd and periodic function, with period $L>0$. If we define
$$g(x):=f\left(x-\frac{L}{2}\right), \; \forall \; x \in \mathbb{R},$$
then $g$ is even?

I tried to prove it, as follows: let $x \in\mathbb{R}$ arbitrary. Thus,
$$g(-x)=f\left(-x-\frac{L}{2}\right)=f\left(-\left(x+\frac{L}{2}\right)\right)=-f\left(x+\frac{L}{2}\right).$$

But I couldn't conclude that $g(-x)=g(x)$.

Is this true in general? What did I do is right?

Comment: did you use that $f$ is periodic?

Comment: I couldn't see where you use that hypothesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your last line,
$$g(-x)=-f(x+L/2)$$
$$=-f(x-L/2+L)$$
$$=-f(x-L/2)=-g(x)$$
$g$ is in fact odd.

Comment: If $g(x):=f\left(x-\frac{L}{4}\right)$ then $g$ is even?

Comment: No. A simple counterexample: Consider $f(x)=\tan x$ which is odd and periodic with period $2\pi$.  It is simple to see by the tangent addition formula that
$$g:x\mapsto f(x-2\pi/4)$$ is also odd.

Answer (score 3):

I think $g(x)$ is odd.

$g(-x)=f(-x-L/2)=f(-x+L/2)=-f(x-L/2)=-g(x)$

Comment: Why $$f\left(-x-\frac{L}{2}\right)=f\left(-x+\frac{L}{2}\right)?$$

Comment: because it is given that $f$ has period $L$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner if $g(x):=f\left(x-\frac{L}{4}\right)$ then $g$ is even?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get even function, then for $\left( -\frac{L}{2}, \frac{L}{2} \right)$ let's define:
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases} f(x), & x>0 \\
-f(x), & x<0
\end{cases}
$$